# chromedriver proxy settings are disabled

Tags: ruby, google-chrome

I am facing wierd issue with google chrome while accessing it through chromeDriver in Ruby Cucumber test case automatic execution. I was able to open an Intranet URL in chrome manullay where as the same URL is not opening during automatic ruby execution process. I am getting 'ERR_NO_SUPPORTED_PROXIES' error, after validating the settings of chrome opened by chromedriver I found that 'Change Proxy settings' option under netwrok is disabled and those settings are not my default settings. 
Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please edit your question to show the code you've tried, and the full exact error message. It's best to provide a minimal failing example if possible.